# mysql num row no me funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Hola necesito agregar paginacion a mi sitio. específicamente es una pre visualización de un reporte de 3000 registros y quiero mostrar en cada pagina 100
esta es mi consulta:

```
$sql ="SELECT documento.* FROM documento 
LEFT JOIN ubicacion ON (ubicacion.documento_id = documento.documento_id)
WHERE unidad_id IN(
   SELECT u.unidad_id FROM unidad AS u,estructura AS e 
   WHERE u.estructura_id = e.estructura_id 
   AND e.padre_estructura_id =3) 
AND estado_documento_id NOT LIKE '7'
GROUP BY documento_id limit 0,100"
```

y para hacer el conteo total de los documentos tengo esto:

```
$cnt = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
```

pero cuando miro el sitio solo me aparecen 100 registros y no puedo cambiar de pagina solo me aparece 1 de 1 cuando deberian ser alrededor de 3O paginas.

este es el metodo :

```
  $cntp = ($cnt % $ipp > 0)+(int)($cnt / $ipp);

  print "<div align=center>" . $lan["page"] . " <select onchange='submit();' name=showfrom>";


  for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i+=$ipp)
  {
      $pn = 1+(int)($i/$ipp);
      print "<option value=$i ".($_POST['showfrom'] == $i ? "selected" :    "").">$pn</option>";
  }
  print "</select> " . $lan["of"] . " $cntp</div></form>";
```

Comment: Si tu consulta siempre es limit 0,100 como esperas que te regrese del 100, al 200? y en todo caso como realizas la paginación?

Comment: en realidad ese limit lo paso por parámetros, asi mira :                                   limit ".$_POST['showfrom'].",$ipp"; @Sergio1871

Comment: Entonces eso deberías ponerlo en tu pregunta la forma en que realizas la consulta en general y también información de tu paginación ya que ahí puede estar el problema tambi´rn

Comment: el campo `unidad_id` en qué tabla aparece?

Comment: @amenadiel pasa que las tablas que estoy haciendo llamados no tienen relacion alguna por eso tanto left join pero el campo unidad viene de una tabla llamada unidad. esa consulta en navicat me arroja 3000 registros por lo que funciona pero hice un echo al count y arroja 0

Comment: a mysql_query() le falta un segundo parámetro, la conexión a la base.

Comment: @Gabrielpeña, `mysql_num_rows` funciona correctamente ya que la cantidad máxima de registros devueltos por tu consulta será `100` (eg: `LIMIT 0,100`) y tu lo que necesitas es saber cuántos hay en total (eg: sin `LIMIT`). Lee la [respuesta de amenadiel](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56064/16597)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer una consulta inicial para conocer el número total de documentos:

```
$sql_conteo ="SELECT count(distinct documento_id) as total 
       FROM documento 
       LEFT JOIN ubicacion ON (ubicacion.documento_id = documento.documento_id)
       WHERE unidad_id IN (
             SELECT u.unidad_id 
             FROM unidad AS u,estructura AS e 
             WHERE u.estructura_id = e.estructura_id 
             AND e.padre_estructura_id =3) 
       AND estado_documento_id NOT LIKE '7'";
```

Eso te va a dar el número de páginas para alimentar tu paginador, y esa consulta es constante (porque el paginador siempre tiene el mismo total de páginas, independiente de la página que estés mirando)

Y luego hacer tu consulta para obtener los 100 registros de la página actual

```
$sql ="SELECT documento.* FROM documento  
       FROM documento 
       LEFT JOIN ubicacion ON (ubicacion.documento_id = documento.documento_id)
       WHERE unidad_id IN (
             SELECT u.unidad_id 
             FROM unidad AS u,estructura AS e 
             WHERE u.estructura_id = e.estructura_id 
             AND e.padre_estructura_id =3) 
       AND estado_documento_id NOT LIKE '7'
       GROUP BY documento_id limit $desde,$hasta";
```

Sin saber más de tu código, no te puedo decir mucho más, salvo que:

- No es buena práctica usar joins implícitos (como haces en tu tabla derivada)
- Probablemente puedas reescribir la condición `IN` haciendo un JOIN con unidad y estructura
- Interpolé las variables $desde y $hasta suponiendo que las obtienes del $_POST
- Es una mala idea interpolar variables de esa manera pero las sentencias preparadas escapan al alcance de esta pregunta

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. mira edite la pregunta y agregue como el metodo donde se hace el conteo completo de las paginas para ver si me puedes ayudar y a entenderlo mas. muchas gracias

Comment: Ok, entonces sólo tienes que preocuparte de asignar a $cnt el valor de la primera consulta. Ojo, el valor, no el conteo de filas, porque esa query sólo devuelve una fila.

Comment: Estás seguro? cuando es el único campo en el SELECT no debiera pedirlo

Comment: @MarcosGallardo siii tienes todas la razón. Usé la primera query como molde y olvidé editar esa parte. Gracias

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS POR TODA SU AYUDA ! . les agradezco enormemente ahora si me funciono.